# Estimation of $\|(1-\Delta)^{\gamma/2}f\|_1$ type

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\phi(\xi)\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with value $1$ in a neighborhood of the unit ball and vanishing fast outside the ball.

I want to estimate
$$\|(1-\Delta)^d (\cdot)^\alpha \partial^\alpha\phi(\cdot)\|_1.$$

By using the result from psudo-differential operator, I am only able to get a boundedness result for $p\in(1,\infty)$.

Actually, given that $\phi$ is bounded and has a compact support, it should not be so difficult to estimated. But I cannot figure out the way to do it.

And suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to get in the right hand side? what does the dot $(\cdot)$ represent?

Comment: What is your $p$?

Comment: @timur $(\cdot)^\alpha$ is what will be integrated. You can replace it by $x$ if you want. Also, $\phi$ is a function of $x$. As for RHS, I want to have an estimation by any norms of $\phi$ (since it is in $\mathcal{S}$, we have many choices), or an  independent constant (which is even better).

Comment: @gerw $p$ is from $L^p$ norm.

Comment: Just to understand what kind of bound you want, it should be possible to bound it by something like $r^{d+|\alpha|}\|\phi\|_{C^{2d+|\alpha|}}$, where $r$ is the diameter of the support of $\phi$. Would it count?

Comment: @timur Sure it counts. I get how to put the radius out, but stuck with how to get rid of the Laplacian. And is it possible that $\|\phi\|$ is bounded by the supremum norm, by any chance?

Comment: The norm is not the supremum norm, it is the $C^{2d+|\alpha|}$ norm. I just used the Leibniz rule to move the Laplacian through $x^\alpha$.

Comment: @timur Oh I see. Thanks.